# Children links disappear when access to parent blocked

Tags: 6, routes

When blocking access to a page -- its child links get skipped both in code and display.

The block is achieved via an access callback attached to the menu item that checks whether the user is logged in or not.

The desired behavior is to show the links regardless of the login status.

Any hints?

P.S. I'm using drupal6

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Drupal Answers. How are those links generated? Are links added from a module with `hook_menu()`, or are links you added through the user interface (a.k.a. the administrative page that adds links to Drupal)?

Answer (score 0):

With the caveat you should be very careful adjusting any core menu item permissions, and I'm presuming you know what you're doing there, it is possible to adjust any menu with

[hook_menu_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!hooks!core.php/function/hook_menu_alter/6)

for example:

```
function mymodule_menu_alter(&$items) {
  // Enable open access for everyone to foo/bar
  $items['foo/bar']['access callback'] = TRUE;
}
```

You can also specify your own access callback there, e.g

```
function mymodule_menu_alter(&$items) {
  // Add custom access callback to foo/bar
  $items['foo/bar']['access callback'] = 'mymodule_special_access';
}

function mymodule_special_access(){
  global $user;
  if($some_condition_is_true){
    return TRUE;
  }
  return FALSE; // default deny
}
```